# Why does the Qu'ran use "Firuan" to refer to pharoah instead of "Al-Firaun"? Isn't Pharoah a definite noun?

Tags: quran, arabic

Basically my question is why the al- prefix omitted when it is used in other places such as an-nabi and al-malik.

Comment: One reason simply could be that different verses refer to different Pharaohs, however in case of Yussuf he wasn't referred to as Fir'uan. And Pharaoh or Fira'un is a title not a name.However there is a notable discussion on whether or not it is the name/surname of that person.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I think the mainstream understanding is that there is only one pharaoh during the time of Moses. So tiltes don't have to have the al- prefix? Someone told me all titles are prefixed by al-. So it becomes The King or The Pharaoh.

Comment: I read a bit about the topic and also have a few assumptions of my own. At least from a scientific point of view the  title pharaoh is rather new as the kings of Egypt had at least two or three other names before this title was established.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Ya I know about the accuracy of using firaun vs malik in the Qu'ran. I believe firaun is never referred to as Al-Firaun because Firaun by itself already means "The Ruler of Egpyt". Anyways, Allah knows best. Jazakallah for responding.